# Unequivalent loop structure in MATLab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have two versions of code - I wrote the second (more explicit) loop when the first didn't do what I wanted.

Where did I go wrong? I suspect a slicing problem (as in, I'm not correctly slicing the data out)

The first version, which doesn't do what I want, is commented out above the loop:

```
rBool = false(h.numDirs, h.numTimes, h.numR);
for d = 1:h.numDirs
    U_first = h.data(d,1,:);
    U_first = U_first{1};
    for t = 2:h.numTimes
        U = h.data(d,t,:);
        U = U{1};
        dU = abs(U-U_first);
        %rBool(d,t,:) = (dU > (smallVal*U_first) | rBool(d,t-1));
        for r=1:h.numR
            rBool(d,t,r) = (dU(r) > (smallVal*U_first(r))| rBool(d,t-1,r));
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the third index of the second `rBool` in your commented line:

```
rBool(d,t,:) = (dU > (smallVal*U_first) | rBool(d,t-1,:));
```

Although I'd parenthesize it like this:

```
rBool(d,t,:) = (dU > (smallVal*U_first)) | rBool(d,t-1,:);
```

The version you originally had implicitly assumed `r==1`, I think.

And you can simplify your code by setting

```
U = h.data{d,t,1};
```

instead of cutting out a cell vector and choosing the first element.

Comment: Thanks - the first part of the answer nicely solves this question, and the tip for the cell vector is much appreciated. I'll open another question to see about a faster implementation of indexing, since I think I'll need to provide more information, and it's not the same problem as this question. Link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302712/loading-data-to-vector-rather-than-cell-in-matlab)