# Loading data to vector rather than cell in MATlab

Tags: matlab, vector

I load data from text files into my MATlab function using this code:

```
data = cell(h.numDirs, numDataFilesInFirstDir);
for d = 1:h.numDirs
    % Code to set fileNames, iDir
    for t = 1:size(fileNames,1)
        fId = fopen([iDir, '/', fileNames{t}]);
        % Drop the first two lines (column headers)
        for skip = 1:2
            fgets(fId);
        end
        U_temp = fscanf(fId, '%f %f', [2, Inf]);
        U_temp = U_temp'; % ' transpose (syntax highlighting on SO)
        data(d, t) = {U_temp(:,2)};
        fclose(fId);
    end
end
```

The files should each have the same length (at least for varying `t`, usually for varying `d` or else I have problems later)

Should I be (/ How can I) simplify the code here to avoid (unnecessary?) cells?

I could scan the first data set, then use something like

`data = zeros(h.numDirs, numDataFilesInFirstDir, lengthOfFirstFile)`

but I don't know if that would be any better. Is that a 'better' solution/method?

Comment: Avoiding cells if possible is always better. Cells are slow and bulky.If you expect your files to have the same number of lines, you should just add that as an extra dimension in your `data` array. And then in your [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302488/unequivalent-loop-structure-in-matlab/) you'll have an array with one more dimensions instead of a cell array with elements of vector value. And *then* you can vectorize your loop over `d` as well:) By the way, if you only need `U_temp(:,2)`, I think matlab supports the format specifier `%*f` which will suppress storing.

Comment: Continued: it really boils down to the question whether the size of your vectors is the same for each `(d,t)`. If yes, use an array. If no, then you'll need cells (unless some padding of your values might make sense, that's rarely the case.)

Comment: Ok - thanks, I'll keep that in mind. You should add your first comment as an answer so I can accept and the question can 'close', or whatever.

Comment: I contemplated it, but there are a lot of matlab gurus around. It's possible that someone will provide some actual insight beyond "use an array" or give you a really efficient snippet to use:) We'll see, thanks in the mean time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `dlmread` instead of `fscanf`. Data type is hard since your dimensions vary. I wouldn't pad arrays... any benefit from not using cells would be overcome by the extra complexity and memory hit. Cell arrays are a reasonable choice. I wouldn't worry about preallocation too much in this case actually. Below is a similar option using `structs` with dynamic field names that embed the source directory and filename, for later reference.

```
data = struct();
for d = 1: ...
    for t = 1: ...
        file = fullfile(iDir, fileNames{t});
        range = [3, 1, inf, 2];
        dlm = ' ';
        Utemp = dlmread(file, dlm, range);
        data.(iDir).(fileNames{t}) = Utemp(:, 2);
```